# Changing mixins.scss does not change the CSS files importing it

Tags: sass, liferay, liferay-6, mixins, liferay-theme

Here is what we are doing:

- we are creating a hook to modify the `\html\css\common\_mixins.scss` file.

The file when deployed is updated. So far so good.

The problem is the CSS files which are importing this mixin are not showing any changes, for example this file - `\webapps\ROOT\html\css\taglib\navbar.css`.

After some debugging I found that there is a `.sass-cache` folder in `\webapps\ROOT\html\css\taglib\.sass-cache` which also has the final generated file `navbar.css` which is used by the portal.

Now when I deploy the hook all the CSS files which import this mixin are not recompiled/regenerated in `.sass-cache` folder, which makes the hook useless.

Can somebody tell me if there is any way to make use of this mixin or is there anyother way to do this or may be I can manually recompile all the CSS files using this mixins if only I knew how to.

Also I see that deleting the `.sass-cache` is not an option since this folder is also used by liferay to patch CSS files if there is a hot-fix.

**Environment**

Liferay EE 6.2 SP9 bundled with Tomcat

---

**Reason** <sub>from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713265/changing-mixins-scss-does-not-change-the-css-files-importing-it#comment42057655_26730875)</sub>

The reason why we need to change this file is to have a way to disable responsive elements for the navigation-bar. Or better still disable responsiveness for the whole portal. Since the responsiveness is due to the media-query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the changes were not reflected and I think CSS is not meant for hooking.

So after trying a lot of stuff, still we were not able to disable responsiveness, so we applied the following CSS in our `custom.css` in our theme. This worked for the navigation bar, for others we can again include those styles individually.

```html
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .navbar .container {
        position: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .btn-navbar {
        color: initial;
        display: none;
        margin-bottom: initial;
        width: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .btn-navbar > .icon-bar:first-child {
        margin-top: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .btn-navbar > .icon-bar:last-child {
        margin-bottom: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .nav-collapse {
        display: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .nav-collapse.open {
        display: initial;
        height: initial;
        overflow: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .nav-collapse .btn {
        padding: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .navbar-search {
        margin: initial;
        padding: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .navbar-search .btn,
    .navbar .container .navbar-search .btn-link {
        clip: none;
        position: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .navbar-search .form-search {
        margin: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .navbar-search .form-search .input-append {
        display: initial;
        padding-right: initial;
    }
    .navbar .container .navbar-search .form-search .input-append .search-query {
        width: initial;
    }
}
```

This CSS code is taken from [this Liferay forum post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/55322356).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to alter _mixins.scss via hook, and it's not only due to the evil sass-cache.

_mixins.scss is written is SASS and it needs to be compile and store in sass-cache. Every theme includes compiled version of every sass file.

The only way is to build you own theme and change _mixins.scss or any other file in _diff folder.

Why do you need to alter that particular file?

Comment: Well I did alter that file and if I remove the `.sass-cache` folder my changes are shown i.e. to say the changes of `_mixins.scss` are taken. I need file this to customize the `respond-to` mixin. You said ***The only way is to build you own theme and change _mixins.scss or any other file in _diff folder.*** - so how do you apply your changes to the media-queries for taglib and portal folders since those are not part of the theme?

Comment: I think the existence of navbar.css or similar css inside taglib path is a big fault. My way is to change direcly the navbar.css via hook without rewriting theme _mixins.scss. I think it's more safe and secure.

Comment: Yes I am trying that, lets see if it pays off.

Comment: Its seriously amazing, the way it works. Even after changing the navbar.css which changes the same file in .sass-cache folder, still it does not work and finally found that its because of the file `/html/css/main.css` which actually should be updated but updating this file unfortunately does not update the `/html/css/.sass-cache/main.css` and hence it does not work.

Comment: Interesting, navbar.css is also compiled by sass and it falls into sass-cache rules. Very annoying bro. if I were you I'll find a way to force new style for navbar using theme.